# External stylesheet (css) in php

Tags: php, html, css, stylesheet, external

I have looked through 4-5 post on stackoverflow regarding this without solving my problem.

I have a php file and want to use the css stylesheet I have for the other HTML files.

Right now it looks like this:

```
 <div style="height: 600px;">
      <?php
       echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css' media='all'/>";
       session_start();
       $admin = $_SESSION['admin'];
       $author = $_SESSION['author'];
       ?>
       <?php if ($admin == true AND $author == true) { ?>
           <p id="confirmationText"><?echo "Thank you for your message! <br>You should have received a confirmation email. We will contact you soon."; ?></p>
       <?php } ?>
</div>
```

It is not working; the p id="confirmationText" text does not get formatted. interestingly, when I just open the file locally without apache server, it will get HTML-formatted.

What to do?

Comment: Have you turned on error messages and are you getting any? There is a typo after `<p id="confirmationText">` - There should be a space between `<?` and `echo`. Note also that echoing strings is pretty pointless, you should just write it in HTML

Comment: awh, that's so mean ): ppl randomly downvoting your question ... do give us more info on the details of your problem please, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you open the stylesheet in your browser?

Also, why are you echoing a stylesheet in a div, and not in the head?

Comment: Ahhh! Of course! I now echoed the stylesheet in the head and it worked! :) Once again, Stack overflow comes to the rescue! :)

Answer (score 1):

- CSS style links sometimes don't work properly if they aren't in the `<head> ... </head>` area. The *best practice* would be to just declare that echo statement up
  there.
- Try opening your page in a browser, and clicking 'inspect
  element' on that place where your stylesheet is linked, and see if you can see any problems there. Often browsers just render things strangely. It can give your clues as to what's wrong.
- Why are you linking the stylesheet *before* your `session_start` command? Perhaps this might just be causing an output buffer error. Try putting your link at the end of the PHP code.

Honestly, sometimes even the "best practice" and "cleanup" methods of fixing code, won't work. You can just use a little css hack. It's bad practice and a bit depreciated but I've been writing code for years and this just makes life so much easier: Instead of linking a stylesheet externally .... imbed the style directly.

Add this piece of code to your file:

```
<style>
<!-- change the path to the correct one, though. I have no clue where your file is, in the filesystem, I'm just guessing, here -->
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/stylesheet.css"); ?> 
</style>
```